# Django CSRF cookie + ReactJS axios post request

Tags: python, django, reactjs, axios

HI I've been stuck on this axios post request for couple days. I'm trying to send a post request to the REST API so that it could create a new data entry in the backend.

After I sent the post request using axios along with XSRF token and CSRF token, I always got "OPTIONS /endpointURL HTTP/1.1" 200 0" instead of the actual post request:

[image: console]

Here's my code for the axios post request

```
import axios from '../helpers/axios';

axios({
  method: "post",
  url: "http://endpointurl",
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': localStorage.getItem('xsrftoken'),
    'csrftoken': localStorage.getItem('csrftoken')
    // 'XSRF-TOKEN': localStorage.getItem('userToken')
  },
  data: {
    name: this.state.name,
  }
}).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      console.log(res.data);
})
```

I also tried to send a wrong token along with the post request, I would still get "OPTIONS ..."

../helpers/axios

```
import axios from 'axios'

/**
 * Config global for axios/django
 */
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFToken"
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'

export default axios
```

And this is how I got the tokens

```
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
var xsrftoken = getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');

localStorage.setItem('csrftoken', csrftoken);
localStorage.setItem('xsrftoken', xsrftoken);
```

Thank you!!

Comment: The browser will precede a `POST` request with an `OPTIONS` request first. [See Mozilla's documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS)

Comment: @RossRogers I've never got the POST request after OPTIONS request. Is there any way to avoid OPTIONS request or trigger POST?

Comment: If Django didn't get the post, then Django's `OPTIONS` response may not have told the browser that a `POST` was a legal response.  Look at the `Allow` header response like `Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST`.  The `Allow` header must have the `POST` request type.  If you're using chrome, open the debugger with `ctrl` + `shift` + `j`, click on the network tab and then rerun your jQuery code.

Comment: @RossRogers I just attached a screenshot of the Allow header response. It does allow POST request type

Comment: I see the screenshot.  Do you see that `Error: Network Error` ?  You might need to dig in there.  If you're running linux, you can [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) it with `socat  -v TCP-LISTEN:8080,forever,reuseaddr,fork TCP:192.168.0.192:3000` and then route your http requests to the 8080 port.  Also, you probably need to use a non `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` address.  Find your local network IP and use that instead.  Otherwise the browser won't send session credentials to your django backend.